# How do I write a Formula for the pattern I have made in a grid?

Tags: functions

How do I write a formula to express the pattern that is in the grid I have made?

[image]

Comment: If you put $1$s everywhere in the first row and first column, then look at the grid "diagonally", you'll see a familiar *triangular* configuration.

Comment: This is a well-known pattern (hint: look at the anti-diagonals) known as Pascal's Triangle.

Comment: There's an error, $21+35\neq 46$, fourth column sixth row

Comment: Thanks Teresa there is your absolutely right! my bad I was trying to knock a grid up quickly for a visual on here and missed it in my rush!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This grid can be represented as a matrix P satisfying:

$$ P_{m,n} = \frac{(m+n)!}{m!n!} = \begin{pmatrix} m+n \\ m \end{pmatrix} $$